pnas-new template: extra large space after bottomrule?
I am using the pnas-new template in Overleaf (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/tagged/pnas-official), in particular the template for research report. I notice that when adding a line of text (more specifically, a \multicolumn) below \bottomrule in a tabular, there is an extra space added, which is not the case when the same code is used in a non-pnas template.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this extra large space? Note that there is an extra command, \addtabletext but it seems to do the same, and add a large space below the table too.
Here is the code (also available through overleaf):
\documentclass[9pt,twocolumn,twoside]{pnas-new}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\templatetype{pnasresearcharticle}

\begin{document}

\title{Template for preparing your research report submission to PNAS using Overleaf}
\significancestatement{\lipsum[1]}

\begin{abstract}\lipsum[1]\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\thispagestyle{firststyle}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{shortarticle}}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{singlecolumn}}{\abscontentformatted}{\abscontent}}{}

\begin{table}[t!]
\centering
\caption{Table}
\begin{tabular}{lrrr}
Species & CBS & CV & G3 \\
\midrule
1. Acetaldehyde & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
2. Vinyl alcohol & 9.1 & 9.6 & 13.5 \\
3. Hydroxyethylidene & 50.8 & 51.2 & 54.0\\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Some text below the table}
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\subsection*{Digital Figures}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}



I found out the issue: this is a desired feature of the pnas-new template, which sets: \setlength{\belowbottomsep}{10pt} (and I believe the default booktabs value is 0pt).
This seems quite huge looking at various PNAS papers. Should one wish to modify it for some reason, it suffices to do re-add this line in the preamble:
\setlength{\belowbottomsep}{2pt}.
PS: theoretically, the pnas-new template provides a command for table footnote/comments, \addtabletext{} but this also faces some issues (huge space and centered).

No need to change the defaults set by the class. Just use
\begin{tabular}{lrrr}
Species & CBS & CV & G3 \\
\midrule
1. Acetaldehyde & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
2. Vinyl alcohol & 9.1 & 9.6 & 13.5 \\
3. Hydroxyethylidene & 50.8 & 51.2 & 54.0\\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\addlinespace[0pt]
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Some text below the table} \\
\bottomrule[0pt]
\end{tabular}


If you remove the trailing \bottomrule[0pt] you get

Compare with what you get without the \multicolumn line and the standard \bottomrule:

Apparently, the people at PNAS want this type of output.
